# Partition an unpartitioned table in ADX

Tags: azure-data-explorer, adx

I have a table where we don't have a partition policy. Data is ordered based on the ingestion time. When I went through this blob post https://yonileibowitz.github.io/blog-posts/data-partitioning.html#backfill-or-unordered-ingestion I realized overriding this policy will solve a lot of problems which I am facing now. In my case i have table lets call it as `RAW_INOMING_DATA` its fields are T-> Time stamp of the packet, DATA -> Raw data generated at the time T. Now I need to override the partition in this table so that I can make T as the Ingestion_Time. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the ideal solution for your scenario is that you pre-partition the data at the source by the relevant datetime property (if it's not already pre-partitioned), then specify the `creationTime` ingestion property when you ingest it.
- if the data is already ingested, you can set a [uniform range datetime partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy#uniform-range-datetime-partition-key), with the column name being the property of your data you want to partition by. This will improve the efficiency of filtering on that datetime column at query time.

  - if you also want the retention policy and caching policy to be applied according to the values in that column, set the `overrideCreationTime` propety of the partition key to `true`.
  - an example for the command to run for setting such a partition key, as appears in the documentation:

  ````
  .alter table TableName policy partitioning ```{
    "ColumnName": "timestamp",
    "Kind": "UniformRange",
    "Properties": {
      "Reference": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
      "RangeSize": "7.00:00:00",
      "OverrideCreationTime": false
    }
  }```
  ````

Comment: Great I got answer from the Author of the blog itself. Thanks a lot Yoni :)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioning-policy#alter-and-alter-merge-policy) of the partitioning policy has the exact syntax of the command. For example:

````
.alter table [table_name] policy partitioning ```
{
  "PartitionKeys": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "my_string_column",
      "Kind": "Hash",
      "Properties": {
        "Function": "XxHash64",
        "MaxPartitionCount": 128,
        "PartitionAssignmentMode": "Uniform"
      }
    }
  ]
}```
````

If you're still missing some info, please let us know.

Comment: please note that this example includes a *hash* partition key, whereas the proper kind of partition key to use in this scenario is a *uniform range datetime *partition key